# Поиск элемента в списке по отрывку Python

Tags: python, list

Задался вопросом, как найти элемент в списке Python, пример.
Есть в папке файл test.py и .zip с неизвестным именем, мне нужно его найти, но тот же directlist.index, работает только по полному названию, и если попробовать то будет ошибка - элемент не найден.

```
direct = os.getcwd()
directlist = os.listdir(direct)
print(directlist)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Взял псевдокод @Эникейщик 'ка и перевёл на язык питон

```
import os
direct = os.getcwd()
directlist = os.listdir( direct )
for element in directlist :
 if '.zip' in element : 
   print( element )
```

Comment: можно даже использовать не ``in``, а ``endswith``, чтобы было точно в конце, а не в середине.

Comment: @Эникейщик большое спасибо )

Answer (score 3):

Псевдокод:

```
для каждого element в directlist:
    если ".zip" содержится в element:
        print("Урааа! нашел!", element)
        делай с element все что хочется
```

Comment: Хмм. Это сработает, но мне нужно именно имя файла, выцепить его и взаимодействовать, а в псевдокоде, просто .zip ГДЕ то есть, а вот ищи его сам.

Comment: @L2R2 если ```.zip``` есть, то в этот момент перебор файлов останавливается и вам возвращается имя файла в переменной ```элемент```

Comment: я вам дополнил псевдокод так, что теперь вам даже известно в каком именно элементе содержится .zip. Это elementарно.